# How can I perform string concatenation in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array(['a','b'])
b = np.array(['baby','king'])
```

how can I get this result in python?

```
c = ['a_baby','b_king']
```

Comment: Why shall the result be a list instead of an array?

Answer (score 4):

You can use numpy's `add` [string operation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.char.html):

```
c = np.char.add(np.char.add(a, '_'), b)
print(c)
```

Result:

```
['a_baby' 'b_king']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['a','b'])
b = np.array(['baby','king'])

def concat_arrays(a, b):
    try:
        assert(len(a)==len(b)) #To check if both the arrays are of equal length    
    except:
        print("arrays not equal")
    else:
        c=[]
        for i in range(len(a)):
            c.append(a[i] + "_" + b[i])
        return c

c = concat_arrays(a, b)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['a_baby', 'b_king']
```

Answer (score 0):

With dtype object, you can just add ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xbsMwDEV3noJxBtloYQ/dCmTKKYqiCCiFbdTElCDJAbQ1lwmQJYfyRRwZnoJyIAG@/z@@z@ng5G2abO9dSChD7zNSRPFAuCmnpRAo15@K1KvS6qsB/fzXpHNBRys/MwVTMLUUU/ZcO/3LJjX4gmqnytYAPlhJtWmmab3qhhg6baVjOaNfugCQMRzj7sRnPpWwaogcKrDf@ARWG1TihMe/@3i5qndc4/bA5oizcN9bwfFymwmS7P9b51DAMkuf6sMNSIGLeHG3VfMA)):

```
c = a.astype(object) + '_' + b
```

Or if you really want a list as you've shown:

```
c = (a.astype(object) + '_' + b).tolist()
```